# replace square brackets java

Tags: java, replace, brackets

I want to replace text in square brackets with "" in java:

for example I have the sentence

`"Hello, [1] this is an example [2], can you help [3] me?"`

it should become:

"Hello, this is an example, can you help me?"

Answer (score 14):

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll("\\[\\d+\\] ", "");
```

What this does is to replace all occurrences of a regular expression with the empty String.

The regular expression is this:

```
\\[  // an open square bracket
\\d+ // one or more digits
\\]  // a closing square bracket
     // + a space character
```

Here's a second version (not what the OP asked for, but a better handling of whitespace):

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll(" *\\[\\d+\\] *", " ");
```

What this does is to replace all occurrences of a regular expression with a single space character.

The regular expression is this:

```
 *   // zero or more spaces
\\[  // an open square bracket
\\d+ // one or more digits
\\]  // a closing square bracket
 *   // zero or more spaces
```

Comment: Good, but you should add an extra space to the front of the expression to get rid of extra spacing.

Comment: @Edwin I added that to the back, but you are right, the front is better

Comment: Added a second version that addresses space

Comment: I'm not sure about all the inputs available, but I prefer not to process the space along with the tag. Inputs such as `[1] A B [4], C D [5] E F [8].` may not be processed correctly.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "").replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

Comment: Why would you assume that multiple spaces should be replaced?

Comment: @beerbajay From the example, where "Hello, [1] this" became "Hello, this"

Comment: @beerbajay: From the sample output.

Comment: Good solution, I'd just like to note the usage of reluctant quantifiers here is why this works meaning it catches [1] instead of [1] this is an example [2] .

Answer (score 2):

Please use this,

```
String str = "[How are you]";
str = str.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","");
```